# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str")

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm doing a pos tagging and the algorithm is Baum-Welch algorithm.
I want to send the types and tags in the .csv file but after running the code this error shows

```
untagged =pd.read_csv('test.csv','UTF-8','r')

print ('Tagging...')

#taggedOutput = doTagging(sent,untagged)

[w for w in sent if w in untagged]

tagged = pd.read_csv("Tagged_bangla_hmm.csv",'a',encoding="utf-8", 

header=None, delimiter = r'\s+',skip_blank_lines=False, engine='python')

for sentence in tagged:

     a = zip('types', 'tags')

     for word, tag in  a:

         tagged.to_csv( types +'/' + tags + ' ')

         print(tagged)

         print('\n\n')

         tagged.close()

         print ('Finished Tagging')

         i=0
```

Comment: `a = zip('types', 'tags')` will `zip` two _strings_. The first element produced will be `('t', 't')`, for example. Is that what you intended to write? Also, what are `types` and `tags` in `types +'/' + tags + ' '`? I suspect `types` is a list, and it's impossible to concatenate the string `'/'` and a list

Comment: No both of them are different
i think type is a method not types

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, write `a = zip(types, tags)` instead of `a = zip('types', 'tags')` Get rid of the quotation marks around `'types'` and 'tags'.

---

Secondly, when you write `types +'/' + tags + ' '`, `types` must be a string and `tags` must be a string. The plus-operator (`+`) cannot add a list and a string together. It can only add a list to a list or a string to a string.